# Content Over Flow Submitted Forms

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have not be able not find anything to answer my question so I will ask it here: How can keep content submitted from a form with the page space? If a form is submitted with really long lines, has not enough space, no spaces or no periods, the content over flows horizontally on my page and ruins the design and content. What can I do to prevent this in my code?

Here is a screenshot [image]

Comment: Although it's absurd to have such long string without space, which is considered as a whole word, try using **truncation** if possible.

Comment: That has nothing to do with what I need. I would like to know how to confine text to my page

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you can avoid an user to enter such text in a form, but you can prevent your result page display by using the CSS property `word-break`:

```css
.content {
  word-break:break-word;
}
```

```html
<p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec varius justo vel ullamcorper viverra. Quisque nec eros felis. Pellentesque cursus id sem quis luctus. Proin sapien libero, accumsan non sollicitudin eu, tincidunt sed lacus.</p>
<p class="content">Loremipsumdolorsitamet,consecteturadipiscingelit.Donecvariusjustovelullamcorperviverra.Quisquenecerosfelis.Pellentesquecursusidsemquisluctus.Proinsapienlibero,accumsannonsollicitudineu,tinciduntsedlacus.</p>
```